# Auth0: unable to find ways to customize "new universal login pages"

Tags: customization, auth0, multi-factor-authentication

**General need**

- customize the MFA widget using the new universal login flow
- this is not equal to classic flow (where we have `Auth0MFAWidget` with a range of options as listed [here](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/multi-factor-authentication/customize-mfa/mfa-theme-language-dictionary))

**Specific need** (for the **new universal login flow**, not the **classic universal login flow**)

- Is there a possibility to change the default country on the MFA-SMS enrollment prompt?
- can we restrict the list of countries also?
- below is the page that I am looking at, can be accessed [here](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/universal-login-pages/universal-login-page-templates):

[image: MFA prompt]

**Note**:

- Asking these for the *new universal login flow*, not the *classic universal login flow*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a support ticket (from a paid company account) and got a reply:

Is there a possibility to change the default country on the MFA-SMS enrollment prompt?

- it is auto selected based on the ip of the user

Can we restrict the list of countries also?

- not available
- workaround is to use JavaScript on the [universal-page-template](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/universal-login-pages/universal-login-page-templates) which hides specific countries using the DOM
- something like:

```
    const allList = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

    Object.keys(allList.children).map(ch => { 
        if (allList.children[ch].innerText.search('Japan') !== -1){
        allList.children[ch].style.display = none;
        }
    });
```